# Venn diagram proportional and color shading with semi-transparency

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I have following type of count data.

```
A   450
B   1800
A and B both    230
```

I want to develop a colorful (possibly semi-transparency at intersections) like the following Venn diagram.

[image]

**Note:** This figure is an example hand drawn in PowerPoint, and it is not to scale.

Comment: Why not start with `library("sos"); findFn("venn")` and see how far that takes you?

Comment: Or use *venneuler* package it does that

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here is a post which discusses [Venn diagram from list of clusters and co-occurring factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153594/venn-diagram-from-list-of-clusters-and-co-occuring-factors).

For easy solution use package [venneuler](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/venneuler/index.html):

```
require(venneuler)
v <- venneuler(c(A=450, B=1800, "A&B"=230))
plot(v)
```

[image]

For more advanced and customized solutions check package [VennDiagram](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/).

```
library(VennDiagram) 
venn.diagram(list(B = 1:1800, A = 1571:2020), fill = c("lightblue", "green"), 
             alpha = c(0.5, 0.5), lwd =0, "venn_diagram.tiff")
```

[image]

Comment: @John: good form is first to read the help files for VennDiagram and venneuler carefully, and only then ask about formatting or other options.

Comment: @John while the `venneuler` doesn't have a "border" argument, you could draw circles based on the value of the `venneuler` object (you have centers and diameters) which would make a border. I suspect this would not be that hard to implement in the function, either.

Comment: @Roman: one could use draw.circle() from the plotrix package for the circles.

Comment: Does the package apply any logic to the data? I gave it this: `v <- venneuler(c(A=100, B=100, "A&B"=50, C=100, "A&C"=25))` and it produced a diagram which included a small intersection between B and C.

Comment: @SabreWolfy: Yeah, interesting, not sure mate. You probably need to tweak some venneuler parameters to get rid of this strange overlap...

Comment: Try:`v <- venneuler(c(A=450, B=1800, "A&B"=425))`
`plot(v)` and notice that the overlap isn't even close to correct. 'A' should be almost completely covered by B. I'm very skeptical of this package.

Comment: @DunderChief I've also encountered what seem to be drastic inaccuracies with this package. I emailed the maintainer but never heard back.

Comment: You might be interested in this, regarding venneuler: http://benfred.github.io/venn.js/tests/venneuler_comparison/

Answer (score 54):

I have recently published a new R package, [eulerr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=eulerr), which does what you want. It is quite similar to venneuler but without its inconsistencies.

```
library(eulerr)
fit <- euler(c(A = 450, B = 1800, "A&B" = 230))
plot(fit)
```

[image: eulerplot]

Or you could try the shiny application for the same r package at [eulerr.co](http://eulerr.co)

[image: shiny-euler]

Comment: The animated shiny app sealed the deal for me

Comment: Excellent package. Minor flaw imho is the default color scheme, which is using white for the first set and background, and thus lacks contrast.
Also the provided code-snippet is not giving the same result with recent R/package version.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code-snippet and the figure it generates. I would disagree with you regarding the color scheme. The contrast with the background is usually not the primary concern and white contrasts very well with most other colors and particularly the label on the circle.

Comment: exactly what im looking for! can you tell me how to do A&BnotC?

Comment: I was surprised/confused by the default "quantities" labels. I was expecting each count label to show the quantity in that region rather than the total so that if you add up all the displayed numbers you get the total N. In your examples, A is 5, but A-only is 3. A&B is 2 but A&BnotC is 1.5.  B is 3, but B-only is 1.  The regional areas also do not appear to be proportionate to their quantities in this respect.

Comment: @BrianD there is not always a perfect fit, so sometimes the areas are not in fact completely area-proportional. You do get the total N if you add up all the areas. This is because I have chosen "disjoint combinations" and not unions for input

Comment: you can also use  the dataset: fit <- euler( data.frame( mtcars[ , c("vs", "am")]) )
> plot( fit)

Comment: The venneuler package above requires Java, but this doesn't, so that was especially nice.

Answer (score 43):

Based on second answer by Geek On Acid second suggestion ( thanks once again ) I would able sove the line problem as well. I am posting if this is relevent to other googlers !

```
  require(VennDiagram)
    venn.diagram(list(B = 1:1800, A = 1571:2020),fill = c("red", "green"),
  alpha = c(0.5, 0.5), cex = 2,cat.fontface = 4,lty =2, fontfamily =3, 
   filename = "trial2.emf");
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm using `vennDiagram(sub, cex=..,lwd=2,circle.col=...)` and when I try `fill` as you mention, it prompts:1: `"fill" is not a graphical parameter` Is this a matter of vennDiagram version? Do you the right 'fill' in this case? Thanks a lot

Comment: @PGreen I just tried in R 2.15.2 with latest version of vennDiagram works for me ....

Comment: @PGreen I suspect the problem is that you are using vennDiagram from the limma package, whereas jon is using venn.diagram from the vennDiagram package. vennDiagram does not have a fill argument, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: Is it possible to print `venn.diagram` to the default R graphics device rather than exporting to tiff (for use in rmarkdown document)?

Comment: @rmf To plot on the R graphics device do `vennPlot = venn.diagram(..., filename=NULL); grid.newpage(); grid.draw(vennPlot)`

Answer (score 17):

Even though this doesnt answer your question completely. I thought that this will be useful for other people looking to plot Venn Diagram.
One can use the venn() function from the gplots package:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gplots/docs/venn

```
## modified slightly from the example given in the documentation
## Example using a list of item names belonging to the
## specified group.
##
require(gplots) 
## construct some fake gene names..
oneName <- function() paste(sample(LETTERS,5,replace=TRUE),collapse="")
geneNames <- replicate(1000, oneName())

## 
GroupA <- sample(geneNames, 400, replace=FALSE)
GroupB <- sample(geneNames, 750, replace=FALSE)
GroupC <- sample(geneNames, 250, replace=FALSE)
GroupD <- sample(geneNames, 300, replace=FALSE)

venn(list(GrpA=GroupA,GrpB=GroupB,GrpC=GroupC,GrpD=GroupD))
```

[image]
Afterwards I just add colours and transparency using illustrator.
[image]

Comment: Hi! Do you mind ellaborating on what you mean by using illustrator? Do you mean Adobe Illustrator, or is there a way to achieve the diagram above just using R?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I mean using Adobe Illustrator

Answer (score 5):

There is an intuitive and flexible proportional plotter that you can download and run. Find it at:
http://omics.pnl.gov/software/VennDiagramPlotter.php

and

**jvenn**: an interactive Venn diagram viewer - GenoToul Bioinfo: http://bioinfo.genotoul.fr/jvenn/

Answer (score 5):

I know that the OP asks about a solution in R but I would like to point to a web-based solution called [BioVenn](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/cdd/biovenn/index.php). It takes up to 3 lists of elements and draws a Venn diagram so that each surface is proportional to the number of elements - like this one:

[image]

In this diagram I have changed manually (via PhotoShop) the placement of the numbers as I did not like the locations chosen by BioVenn. But you can chose not to have numbers.

In theory the lists used with BioVenn shall consist of gene IDs but, in practice, it doesn't matter - the lists simply have to contain strings.

Comment: "In this diagram I have changed manually (via PhotoShop) the placement of the numbers as I did not like the locations chosen by BioVenn. But you can chose not to have numbers." Actually, in BioVenn you can just drag-and-drop the numbers to anywhere you want. No PhotoShop needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: found [this](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn) package for python that does the same thing.