# How can I make the Venn-Diagram colourful in R {venn-gplots}?

Tags: r, venn-diagram, gplots

I used venn function in gplots library.

here is a simple example.

```
library(gplots)
venn( list(A=1:5,B=4:6,C=c(4,8:10),D=c(4:12)) )
```

and here is the output:

[image]

my question is how can I make this picture colourful for each group? (basically make it more fancy! :D)

I've tried another packages but as my data are not numeric they would not accept characters to make a diagram!

Any help/advise would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: _"my data are not numeric"_ - well then you shouldn't provide numeric example data IMHO.

Comment: You might find this question useful, but essentially the answerer used gplots' venn and Illustrator to color the parts.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713994/venn-diagram-proportional-and-color-shading-with-semi-transparency

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either export your image as svg and colorize it with - e.g. - InkScape, or use another package:

```
require(VennDiagram)
vp <- venn.diagram(list(A=1:5,B=1,C=c(4,8:10),D=c(4:12)), 
                   fill = 2:5, alpha = 0.3, filename = NULL);
grid.draw(vp)
```

[image]