# VennDiagram is not generating proportional graph

Tags: r, graphics, venn-diagram

I have written a simple code using VennDiagram,

```
venn.diagram(list("All Patents" = 1:140188, "Influential Patents" = 1:43271, "Valuable Patents" = 23314:90029), 
         col = 'transparent', fill = c("yellow", "orange", "green"), alpha = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
         cex = 1, cat.fontface = 4, cat.pos = 1, cat.cex = 0.75, cat.dist = -0.03,
         cat.fontfamily = 'serif', scaled = TRUE, filename = "Patent_Venn_Diagram.emf");
```

[image]

However, the graph I generate is not proportional. Can someone please suggest me how to get a scaled plot.

Comment: Maybe you should drop "All Patents", then it gives proportional venn.

Comment: @zx8754 But I require proportional along with that variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try other packages, maybe venneuler? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713994/venn-diagram-proportional-and-color-shading-with-semi-transparency

Comment: @zx8754 Nope. I didn't try other packages. Given the comments, I think there is some problem with venneuler package. Also, VennDiagram package is way more advanced.

Comment: This sentence on the help page might help `scale = "Enable scaling for two-set and certain three-set Euler diagrams. (euler.d must be true to enable this)"`. I think your venn don't belong to such certain diagrams. I recommend to plot without "All Patents" and use an image editing software to include the missing circle by your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to switch to another package, here is a solution using my `eulerr` (which I am the author of), after having edited your input slightly.

```
library(eulerr)

mod <- c("All Patents" = 50159, "Influential Patents&All Patents" = 23313,
         "Valuable Patents&All Patents" = 46758,
         "All Patents&Influential Patents&Valuable Patents" = 19958)

fit <- euler(mod)

plot(fit)
```

[image: Imgur]