# Draw two circles proportional

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I have two counts, one of total numbers of orders, one of unique customers. What I want to make is a plot consisting of two (proportional) circles, an outer one for the total number of order and an inner one for the unique customers.

This is what I got so far, and it's close in terms of how I want it to look, but the circles are not proportional? I'm open to other options than geom_circle. I tried working with geom_point and setting the n to size, but I got two smalls dots in a big empty plot.

```
library(ggforce) 

X <- structure(list(n = c(16836L, 9017L), Type = c("Total n order", "Unique customers")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(X) + 
  geom_circle(
    aes(x0 = 0, y0 = n, r = n),
    linewidth =4,
    colour="black"
  ) + 
  geom_circle(
    aes(x0 = 0, y0 = n, r = n),
    linewidth =1,
    colour = "white"
  ) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you might need a venn diagram.

Comment: Related post about proportional Venn - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8713994/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using dedicated [Venn Diagram packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8713994/680068). If we want to go with circles then we can extract Radius from Area:

```
X$R <- sqrt(X$n/pi)

ggplot(X) + 
  geom_circle(
    aes(x0 = 0, y0 = R, r = R),
    linewidth =4,
    colour="black"
  ) + 
  geom_circle(
    aes(x0 = 0, y0 = R, r = R),
    linewidth =1,
    colour = "white"
  ) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! I tried using Venndiagram, adding a new rowcount id-value to the orders and the unique customers. This way I got 1:16836 for the order and 1:9017 for the customers, which did the job, except the circles where placed inside each other and not aligned to the left like I would have wanted. I had to add an dummy row in the customers vector just so it would force the circle to the side. Your solution does the trick better. You understood my question better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty version using `ggvenn`. Possibly need more details in the question to understand explicitly what you are attempting to achieve.

```r
library(ggvenn)

X = list("Total n order" = 1:16836,
         "Unique customers" = 1:9017)

ggvenn(X, c("Total n order", "Unique customers"),
       auto_scale = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>