# Venn diagram for non-numeric entries to be shown in subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, venn-diagram

I have the folowing dataframe:

```
SET1 SET2 SET3
par1 par2 par1
par2 par3 par2
par3 par4 par5
...  ...  ...
```

I would like to make a Venn diagram in that all those 'parX' elements are shown in respective subets i.e. as labels, not just the number of overlapping elements. 
Which R package supports that?

Comment: cran vennDiagram package

Comment: I have looked into this but the manual/package is an example of how not to write one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the best answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019794/venn-diagram-with-item-labels)  you have to add labels manually (using VennDiagram), when you have two circles it's pretty easy, however if you have three or more, whole stuff becames more complex

```
library(VennDiagram)



SET1 <- c('a','b','c','d')
SET2 <- c('a','e','f','g')
SET3 <- c('a','w','x','f')



v <- venn.diagram(list(SET1 = SET1, SET2 = SET2, SET3 = SET3),
                  fill = c("red", "green","blue"),
                  alpha = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), cat.cex = 1.5, cex=1.5,
                  filename=NULL)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v)


v[[7]]$label  <- paste(setdiff(SET1, intersect(SET2,SET3)), collapse="\n") 
v[[8]]$label <- paste(setdiff(intersect(SET1,SET2),intersect(SET1, intersect(SET2,SET3))), collapse="\n")
v[[9]]$label <- paste(setdiff(SET2, intersect(SET1,SET3)), collapse="\n")
v[[10]]$label <- paste(setdiff(intersect(SET3,SET1),intersect(SET3, intersect(SET1,SET2))), collapse="\n")
v[[11]]$label <- paste(intersect(SET1, intersect(SET2,SET3)), collapse="\n")
v[[12]]$label <- paste(setdiff(intersect(SET2,SET3),intersect(SET2, intersect(SET1,SET3))), collapse="\n")
v[[13]]$label <- paste(setdiff(SET3, intersect(SET1,SET2)), collapse="\n")


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Btw, if I have many elements, as in most real-life applications, the representation is less then ideal - are there any ways to fit all elements into the subsets where they belong?

Comment: Actually the separator used in the example above is new line, so we have columns in circles. I think the better way to do such visualisation is `ggplot`. Nice described [here](https://scriptsandstatistics.wordpress.com/2018/04/26/how-to-plot-venn-diagrams-using-r-ggplot2-and-ggforce/)