# Venn Diagram in R to show character labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn-diagram

I'm very new to R and trying to create a 4-dimensional Venn diagram with a data which contains all categorical variables.
For instance, if i have the data below and I want to create a Venn Diagram in R to show the word "hello" at the intersection of A & B instead of the counts and percentages, how do i do that? I used the code `ggVennDigram(x)` after creating the list below and it gave me the counts instead of the actual data labels.

```
x=list()                        
x$A=as.character(c("hello"))
x$B=as.character(c("hello", "how", "are"))
x$C=as.character(c("how", "You"))
x$D=as.character(c("me", "her", "they"))
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add the name of the library to your question.  Also please include the code you tried.   That will make it a better question and more useful to future readers.

Comment: library(ggplot)                                                                                 
 library(VennDiagram)                                                                                                                                                                                            
 x=list()                        
x$A=as.character(c("hello"))
x$B=as.character(c("hello", "how", "are"))
x$C=as.character(c("how", "You"))
x$D=as.character(c("me", "her", "they"))                                                                                ggVennDiagram(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph cannot be label by default. This is solution with some hack.
(modified from [Venn Diagram with Item labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019794/venn-diagram-with-item-labels/45906498))

```
library(VennDiagram)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# Generate plot
v <- venn.diagram(x,
                  fill = c("orange", "blue", "red", "green"),
                  filename=NULL)

# Calculate overlap site
overlaps <- calculate.overlap(x)
overlaps <- overlaps[str_sort(names(overlaps), numeric = TRUE)] # sort base on numeric value

# Apply name to global variable
# Index of venn diagram start at calculate.overlaps + 8. You have to find the index value by yourself for (3,5,6,7,.. venn)
walk2(seq(overlaps) +8, seq(overlaps),  
      function(x,y) {v[[x]]$label <<- paste0(overlaps[[y]], collapse = "\n")})

# Draw plot
grid.draw(v)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I'm very new to R so i will digest the code a bit and come back with any questions.